# i am not able to create ReverseGeocodeRequest instant in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using Geocode Service in wp7 to get CountryName from  Latitude and Longitude
I wrote following things : -

```
GeoCoordinate location1 = null;
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
    public void FindCountryUsingGps()
    {
        progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
        watcher.Start(); 

    }

    void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        if (watcher != null)
        {

            watcher.Stop();
            watcher.Dispose();
            watcher = null;

            location1 = e.Position.Location;
            ObtainCountry();//by this function you obtain country region
        }
    }
```

then added following reference :-
[image]
after that 
I wrote

```
public void ObtainCountry()
        {
            if (location == null)
                return;

            ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();
```

but i'm not able to write this
**ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();**
 line , it's comes as red

in wp7 , what's this?

Comment: Please supply more information. Have you added a service reference? Is it the Bing Geocoding service or something else? What have you tried? Is it a compile time error?

Comment: Are you sure adding the service reference generated the right code? I've sometimes had issues where the code didn't get generated or was being generated in a namespace I hadn't added a "using" for. The code should be under the ServiceReference folder, in a code file called Reference.cs (or something like that)

Comment: you are right! "I've sometimes had issues where the code didn't get generated" :( i created new project it's working :D :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my response below as an answer so other people who come by can find it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing/re-adding the service reference. Sometimes I've had issues where the code didn't get generated properly. The code should be under the ServiceReference folder, in a code file called Reference.cs.